# post files into ajax json type array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to achieve this following scenario :

As file Object are getting posted through but in string format, how can i get file objects into php file.

Passed data:

```
Array (7)
0 {name: "title", value: "ABC"}
1 {name: "lat", value: "4.627044746156027"}
2 {name: "lng", value: "3.724853515625"}
3 {name: "area_id", value: "1"}
4 {name: "_token", value: "7G643pPBJxxEkfaXrYkZq7e3sBcdQjcmekoPVRAB"}
5 {name: "file[]", value: File}
6 {name: "file[]", value: File}
```

Returned data:

```
["[object File]", "[object File]"]
```

I need to parse the files into laravel but unable to get the file object values.

note: i want to achieve this without `FormData`.

following is the code to pass data:

```
function ajaxRequest(postUrl, method, postData) {
    postData.push({name: '_token', value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')});

    if(files !== undefined) {
        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
            postData.push({name: 'file[]', value: file});
        });
    }

    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
        url: dataUrl + postUrl,
        method: method,
        data: postData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // eval('toastr.' + data.class + '("' + data.message + '")');
            // window.setTimeout(function() { location.reload(); }, 2000)
        },
        error: function() {
            toastr.error("An error occured, please try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Files are binary data. As such you need to send them in a FormData object, not as JSON or a form-url-encoded string

Comment: As the other comment posted its binnary. however you can convert it to say base64. Will that work for you?

Comment: Sure can I have some reference on that. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks and have done with `FormData` following your request. @Sudakatux